# Литература по ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Друзья, подскажите годную литературу по ASP.NET. Более конкретно интересует вопрос создания сайта с помощью данной технологии. Также хотелось бы узнать, с какими технологиями\ЯП совместно применяют ASP.NET. Выражу огромную благодарность за ссылку на хороший пример создания простенького сайта(админ\юзер) с применением данной технологии. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [METANIT](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc.php)
- [Адам Фриман "Pro ASP.NET MVC"](http://smarly.net/pro-asp-net-mvc-4)

Фронт (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) - такой же, как и везде.

В книжке у Фримана в первой части по шагам делают интернет-магазин. Куча важного и полезного еще обсуждается (Dependency Injection, Unit-тестирование, работа с базой данных через Entity Framework).